# Laravel - Custom validation for file doesn't work

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, customvalidator

I am trying to use custom validation rules for file inputs in Laravel. The file input name is "photo". I am trying to apply a rule called "validate_art", to this file input. I know there's "image" validation rule, but I want to apply my own customized rule to this file input.

Here's the code :

```
  $rules = array('name'=>'required|unique:user,name','startyear'=>'numeric','endyear'=>'numeric'
    ,'photo'=>'validate_art');
    Validator::extend('validate_art',function($attribute,$value,$parameters){
    // returning false just for testing purpose
    return false;
    });
```

What happens is, it doesn't apply the rule to the field at all. When I try to use this rule to some other field for testing purposes, it works without failure. Am I doing something wrong? Or custom validation cannot be applied for file inputs? Please someone, throw some light at this. I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Did you open form form files? -> {{ Form::open(['files'=>true, ...]) }}

Comment: Yes I did. But it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you made `Validator::make($input, $rules)` already?

Comment: Post you form here and involved controller methods as well

Comment: `photo` isn't "required" and will therefore not get tested with the "validate_art" rule if it doen't exist in your request. Make sure that there's a field called "photo" in your request that you're passing to the Validator object. Is it a FILE instead of a text field?

Comment: Where did you place the extend? Try to place it 'higher' in the tree of files that are loaded. global.php for example.

Comment: Thank you for checking back. fideloper's response seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: [This may help](http://heera.it/laravel-custom-validation-rule).

Answer (score 0):

first you should modify your input data

```
    foreach ($inputs as $k=>$input){
        if($input instanceOf \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)
            $inputs[$k]=$_FILES[$k];
    }
```

then send $input to validator `$validator=Validator::make($input,$rules)`